# Convert DataRow.fiield from an int to a string

Tags: c#, csv, datarow

I have the following code

```
csvWriter.WriteField<string>(row.Field<string>(column.ColumnName));
```

When the row.Field encounters a data of type int, an error is raised.

Is there a way around this? How can I cast the data from an int to a string in this case.

Comment: What class type is `csvWriter`? Which library belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try something like...

```
csvWriter.WriteField<string>(row.Field<int>(column.ColumnName).ToString());
```

... when you need to retrieve the value of an `int` column.